# How to compute if a multivector inverse exists in Clifford Algebra

Tags: clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

Suppose we have a 4 dimension positive signature clifford algebra. In [Calculating the inverse of a multivector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443555/calculating-the-inverse-of-a-multivector) and [Inverse of a general nonfactorizable multivector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556247/inverse-of-a-general-nonfactorizable-multivector), the inverse of a multivector is presented as a solution when vectors/bivectors are present

$B^{-1} = \frac{B^\dagger}{B B^\dagger}$

but the above is not true for any multivector. For example, how to know if

$(1+e_{1234})^{-1}$

exists and how to compute it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Naively speaking, the existence of inverses will depend on the signature $(p,q)$ of the quadratic space $\mathbb{R}^{p,q}=(\mathbb{R}^{p+q},g)$, in which for an orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^{n=p+q}$ and $v=\sum v^ie_i$ we have
$$g(v,v)=(v^1)^2+(v^2)^2+\cdots+(v^p)^2-(v^{p+1})^2-\cdots-(v^{p+q})^2.$$

For your example, notice that if $(e_{1234})^2=-1$, then
$$(1+e_{1234})\frac{1}{2}(1-e_{1234})=1,$$
which means that $(1+e_{1234})^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}(1-e_{1234})$.

Now, if $(e_{1234})^2=1$, then there is no inverse for $(1+e_{1234})$, which is due to the fact that $x\overline{x}=0$. More specifically, one can [derive](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/74374477.pdf) conditions for which there are inverses for the cases where $p+q=n\leq 5$. The discovery of new faster methods for higher dimensions, which do not depend on the signature is a problem still under development as of today. As an example, we could cite [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.05204.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://doi.org/10.1007/s40314-021-01536-0) paper by D. S. Shirokov (2021) claims to give a basis-free formula using only basic operations and various involutions on multivectors. [Preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.04015).

Comment: (I haven't read this in detail.) In Lemmas 5 and 6, they divide by $3$ to get formulas for the inverse. I wonder if anything really goes wrong when the field has characteristic $3$. Consider this for comparison: If $B$ is a bivector, the expression $B\wedge B\wedge B/6$ seems to be definable even in characteristic $3$.

Comment: @mr_e_man I don't think the $1/3$ is all that important, the real question is whether or not $N(U) = 0 \iff U = 0$ (or some appropriate "scaling" of $N(U)$ that is definable) when you change the characteristic. For your $B\wedge B\wedge B/6$ idea though, perhaps related is the definition of exterior exponential for arbitrary modules given in section 4.5 of *Quadratic Mappings and Clifford Algebras* by Helmstetter and Micali.

Comment: To be a little clearer about my last comment, we would define $${"}B\wedge B\wedge B/6\,{"} = \langle\exp B\rangle_6$$ or more generally $${"}B^{\wedge k}\!/k!\,{"} = \langle\exp B\rangle_{2k}.$$