# Identity element in geometric algebra and computation method for finding the inverse of a multivector

Tags: geometric-algebras

In the book New foundations for classical mechanics by David Hestenes, the  following equation is supposed to be the defining equation multiplicative inverse for a multivector:

$$A^{-1} A = 1$$

Is the $1$ on the RHS a scalar?

[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443555/calculating-the-inverse-of-a-multivector),  [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4034660/invertability-of-a-multivector?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: It would no doubt be helpful if you can define what object $A$ is.

Comment: Oops I had it initially but I deleted it out when editing @JacobA Added back now

Comment: Of course it's the identity element in the geometric algebra. So yes, a scalar.

Comment: There is only one identity in geometric algebra, and that's a scalar.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I think I'll accept if that is posted as answer with an example :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $1$ is meant to be the unit scalar here.  For example, assume that you are considering the multivectors generated by a 2D Euclidean vector space with an orthonormal basis $ \left\{ { \mathbf{e}_1, \mathbf{e}_2 } \right\} $:
$$   \mathbf{e}_1 \mathbf{e}_1 = 1,$$
$$   \left( { \mathbf{e}_1 \mathbf{e}_2 } \right) \left( { -\mathbf{e}_1 \mathbf{e}_2 } \right) = 1,$$
$$   \left( { \mathbf{e}_1 + \mathbf{e}_2 } \right) \frac{ \mathbf{e}_1 + \mathbf{e}_2 }{2} = 1,$$
$$   \left( { 1 + \mathbf{e}_1 \mathbf{e}_2 } \right) \frac{ 1 - \mathbf{e}_1 \mathbf{e}_2 }{2} = 1.$$
All these inverses follow directly from $ \mathbf{e}_1^2 = \mathbf{e}_2^2 = 1 $, and $ \mathbf{e}_1 \mathbf{e}_2 = -\mathbf{e}_2 \mathbf{e}_1 $.

Answer (score -1):

The $1$ on the right is supposed to be the identity (operator or matrix, depending on what sort of thing $A$ is).

Comment: Could you give some examples?